# Cannot use any browser and message app while date is changed

Tags: safari, google-chrome, internet, firefox, web-browser

Does somebody know how to fix internet connection problems when the date on my Mac is not the actual date?

I'm changing the date on my Mac to use a trial version of Parallels desktop because I need to run an old program for Windows for work purposes. I cannot use browser/apps it says "SSL ERROR BAD CERT DOMAIN" or "your connection is not protected...".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Run a legal version of Parallels - and if it is for work then they will pay the fee. Of course if it is not for work then you get to pay…

Comment: From a technical perspective SSL certificates have a start and end date for which they are valid, including the ones built-into web browsers. All web browsers. Like @Solar Mike said pay for Parallels or VMware Fusion, or go the legitimately free route with Virtualbox.

Comment: Or can work supply a pc for that program? It would be a cheap solution…

Comment: VMware Fusion is now free for home use.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you sure about that? Didn't find a "free" version on vmware.com.

Comment: @nohillside - I haven't used it myself, I have Parallels, but it exists - https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal

Comment: As @SteveChambers suggested, try Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the questionable circumstances of your question, most of the time, under a 'more details' or 'advanced' button is the option visit the site anyway, or chrome you can start [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388405/chrome-disable-ssl-checking-for-sites#comment85325294_46702756). Though, it's worth noting that this connection will be unsecured and will put you at risk as the data can be easily read if intercepted.

So, if you do decide to use this method, I'd highly discourage entering any sensitive information **at all**, such as credit cards, passwords, etc. Even just visiting a website that you're logged in to can put you at risk as your browser would have to send a token from a cookie, stored on your computer, to the website in place of your password, which could lead to the token being compromised.

Ultimately, if I were in your position, I wouldn't take the risk and either  use a free alternative (see the comments on your question for recommendations), pay for Parallels, use an old windows laptop, or get your work to provide you another way that doesn't require you to ignore security warnings like this.

Comment: Your advice is also valid on Firefox.